# Yosemite share internet via wifi

Tags: macos, wifi, internet, internet-sharing

I am using internet via wifi connection. Now I want to share my internet with my iphone. In the preferences, I found the option Internet Sharing, but there is no "wifi" option under "To computers using:". "Only ZTE WCDMA Tech" and "Thunderbolt Bridge".

What to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can not bridge from WiFi to WiFi. You'll have to connect to the internet via a different port if you want to share the connection. I'm assuming the reason you don't connect to the network directly with your iPhone is some kind of client limit. You could use a Wireless Router to connect to the WiFi and repeat and reroute it. If you use an Apple Airport make sure you disable bridge mode.

Comment: Ok thanks i have wifi router and will try to repeat the signal. My mac catches the wifi signal but its so weak my iphone cannot connect... Is the wifi device of an iöhone weaker than a mac's?

Comment: MacBooks habe more antennas I believe. The newest have 4. Not sure about the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Please understand following.

You can not receive and transmit from same device (unless is it equipped that way). You Mac is not capable to do that, it is either or.

If you for example receive Internet via cable to your Mac then you can share (transmit) it using your Mac WiFi.

So the input and output can not be the same.

Since you are receiving WiFi, your iPhone and mac should be able to get it from the source.

Comment: Thanks ok. I am connecting to my neighbor's wifi. The signal is weak, so my mac catches it but the iphone does not

Comment: I had that problem once. I purchased a small (inconspicuous device) WiFi repeater. It is a small device and if placed in a plastic bag to protect from rain it can be place outside or on the tree closer to your neighbor with very long extension cord. It will amplify the WiFi signal from the source. I used this one and it worked like charm http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-range-extenders/WN3000RP.aspx

Comment: Thanks yes we used a repeater once in our flat, but tomorrow we will have our broadband fixed, so i was looking for a temporary solution